# Passing two values to the nested restful controller

Tags: php, laravel, restful-url

In my nested restful controller my show method should receives two values like this

```
public function show($postId, $commentsId)
{

// code

}
```

the generated url should be like this

```
http://localhost/posts/1/comments/1
```

Now my query is: I need to send those twu value through my route call

I am using like this :

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('posts.comments.show', value1, value2) }}"> <h3> Click </h3></a>
```

But it is giving an error like this

```
Symfony \ Component \ Routing \ Exception \ InvalidParameterException
Parameter "dcoms" for route "debates.dcoms.show" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.
```

Comment: The second param for `URL::route` should be an array of parameters. See: http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Routing.UrlGenerator.html#_route - that means your code should look like `URL::route('posts.comments.show', [value1, value2])`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by declaring additional route.

You should have something like this:

```
Route::controller('posts', 'RestController');
```

Try to add below following line:

```
Route::controller('posts/{postId}/comments/{commentsId}', 'RestController@anotherShow');
```

And inside your function you have to add function for this route:

```
public function anotherShow($postId, $commentsId)
{

    // code

}
```

You have also change your `URL::route` like this:

```
URL::route('posts.comments.show', array(value1, value2))
```

Or:

```
URL::route('posts.comments.show', array('postId'=>value1, 'commentsId'=>value2))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , But by running the `php artisan routes` in the cmd I can see the route structure is already the as u have mentioned to create. I think the problem is in the like from which the url sends the value or calling the route->controller method.
My question goes more specific like : is it the right way to call e nested url controller by running a anchor tag method such as `<a href="{{ URL::route('posts.comments.show', value1, value2) }}"> <h3> Click </h3></a>'

Because it is just generating an url like : `http://localhost/posts/1/comments/` short for comments parameter.

Comment: Ach i see. I updated my answer, use 'URL::route('posts.comments.show', array(value1, value2))'

Comment: @FDL has solved this array error ! I have posted the full edit. of the link. Thank you for your support !

Answer (score 0):

Now this problem is solved. I am adding this answer here cause It might help you to solve this type of problem.
I want to thank @FDL for his awesome support and also to @kasys .

I had done a single mistake there as I have guessed in comment to the @kasys (@FDL solved this) in generating the url.

In this case the url generating method should be like this

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('posts.comments.show', array(value1, value 2)) }}"><h3>Click this link</h3></a>
```

here the `value1` means the id of posts and `value2` means the id of comments so url would be generated by this link is as ->

`http://localhost/posts/value1/comments/value2`

Thank you @FDL and all those fiends who have participated here. Soon a website will come to rock the world. need your blessings friends :) Thanks !