# Get parameter passed in link with Restful controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I want to get parameter passed into link with Restful Controller ,
This is my routes file :

```
Route::controller('example', 'ExampleController');
```

view :

```
<a href="{{URL::action('ExampleController@getMethode', ['user' => '234'])}}" >xxx</a>
```

Controller :

```
public function getMethode($user) {
    var_dump($user);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810034/passing-two-values-to-the-nested-restful-controller

Answer (score 0):

this is my suggest:
route.php:

```
Route::get('/example/{param1}/{param2}', ['uses' => 'examplecontroller@getparams'])
```

and your controller

```
 public function getParams($param1,$param2){
}
```

for url generate you can pass parameters to route:

```
link_to_action('exampleController@getIndex', $title, $parameters = array(), $attributes = array());
```